# Error in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am creating an UITableView, every thing goes fine in code and build got succeeded, but when I run in simulator. it is showing a error as:

> Thread 1: Program received signal :"EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

find my code below for your refernce:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Mycell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MYcell"]autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %@",(unsigned long)indexPath.row+1];

    return  cell;
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %@",(unsigned long)indexPath.row+1];
```

kindly post your  suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier. %@ is for objects, use %d for integers:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",(unsigned long)indexPath.row+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",(unsigned long)indexPath.row+1];
```

instead of

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %@",(unsigned long)indexPath.row+1];
```